# what is the correct way to use "the" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I need help on the correct grammer to convey this message.

> This tells us if peanuts progress through **the** salt and pepper sprayers.

vs

> This tells us if peanuts progress through salt and pepper sprayers.

I believe this is related to [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114467/omitting-article-the-in-front-of-plural-nouns), but in my example there are two distinct words, "salt" and "pepper".

Comment: The options in question 1 are both grammatical but mean different things.

Comment: I revised the question to remove some ambiguities

Comment: The definite article implies that the reader already knows that the production line includes salt and pepper sprayers.

Answer (score -1):

The correct grammar for the sentence is: "This tells us if peanuts progress through the salt and pepper sprayers."

The sentence "This tells us if peanuts progress through the salt and pepper sprayers" is a way of communicating information about the movement or progression of peanuts through salt and pepper sprayers. The word "tells" is the verb form of "tell" and is in the third-person singular, meaning it is referring to the subject of the sentence, "This." The subject "This" is an unspecified thing or situation, but it is clear from the context that it is referring to some kind of information or observation that is being communicated.
The phrase "if peanuts progress through the salt and pepper sprayers" is a dependent clause that acts as the object of the verb "tells." It is providing more specific information about what the subject is communicating and describes the information as being about the progression of peanuts through the salt and pepper sprayers.

Comment: oops, agree tell should be "tells." I have revised the question to include that correction as it was not pertinent to my main question. Thanks for explaining that part so well. However, your answer does not describe why the word in bold, "the", belongs or not.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).